# Problems with running marathon on my localhost

Tags: mesos, marathon

I have setup mesos and marathon on my local itself. Now, when I begin to start-up mesos master and slave, I get a lot of logs and they seem to start up because I am able to access the web-page http:localhost:5050, but when I start marathon, it gives me this error: `Failed to start a local cluster while loading agent flags from the environment: Flag 'work_dir' is required, but it was not provided`. Though I start the mesos-agent and mesos-slave using the following command,

```
sudo ./bin/mesos-master.sh --ip=127.0.0.1 --work_dir=/var/lib/mesos
```

and `sudo ./bin/mesos-agent.sh --master=127.0.0.1:5050 --work_dir=/var/lib/mesos`

I am not sure where else do I have to configure this flag? Also, one peculiar thing that I see while starting my mesos master is this: `Master bound to loopback interface! Cannot communicate with remote schedulers or agents. You might want to set '--ip' flag to a routable IP address.`

I am not really sure why I am getting this? Any clues? Thanks!

Comment: Were you able to solve this issue when starting marathon ?

Answer (score 1):

Top views of Mesos architecture has Zookeeper component manages master and slave nodes. Agent and Master nodes cannot communication because agent not specifies IP address to Zookeeper service. In command line try to run slave node in the same master machine. Change IP(Not localhost and 127.0.0.1) and Port slave node.   Command line of the slave node.

`$sudo ./bin/mesos-agent.sh --master=127.0.0.1:5050 --work_dir=/var/lib/mesos`

Instead of

```
$ip addr
   2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP qlen 1000 
   net **IPAddr**/24 brd  scope global dynamic eno1
```

`$sudo ./bin/mesos-agent.sh --master=IPAddr:MasterNodePort --ip=IPAddr --port SlaveNodePort --work_dir=/var/lib/mesos`

Support the idea run master and slave nodes in the same machine read at [here.](https://oliverveits.wordpress.com/2016/12/18/getting-started-with-mesos-and-marathon/)

Answer (score 0):

You should set the `--ip` flag's ip address to a routable address, as the error message says. The actual ip address to use strongly depends on you networking setting.

For example, if you're using `en0` a network interface, you can do the following:

```
$ ifconfig en0 inet                                                                                                                          
en0: flags=8863<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    inet 192.168.0.105 netmask 0xffffff00 broadcast 192.168.0.255
```

The ip address `192.168.0.105` would then the the ip to use:

```
sudo ./bin/mesos-master.sh --ip=192.168.0.105 --work_dir=/var/lib/mesos
```

Comment: will this need to be done even if I am running it on my local machine? Won't it be just 127.0.0.1 in that case? Because, I checked my /etc/hosts file and it contains localhost against 127.0.0.1.